# Can I use the CyanogenMod installer on Samsung Galaxy S3 (EE)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, installation

(Note: EE is a british phone service provider.)

I was wondering if I could use the CyanogenMod installer on my Samsung Galaxy S3? It's in the supported devices list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why you couldn't *try* it, because it should either work and install CyanogenMod or it won't manage to install anything.  It doesn't *always* work with my SPH-L710 S3 despite my being able to flash with Odin just fine.

Just **do not** install the *wrong* firmware on your own.  There are over ten different revisions of the S3, and going against what's showing on http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/SGS3FAQ for which specific model you fall under (*most* are considered d2lte now, but not all!) will likely end in a bricked phone.  The differences between the international and the primarily US-only versions are somewhat notorious for bricking the careless.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but I would advise you not to install CyanogenMod, because some parts of your device may not work (WiFi, Bluetooth, camera flash).